# How can I addChild to a SKNode that is declared in the initwithsize method of the gameScene.m file?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

i want to add the block spritenode to the myworld node in the scene. how to do that?

I'm guessing i made a very rookie mistake, or am missing something that is very basic, please bear with me since my first programming language ever is Objective-C.

```
#import "GameScene.h"
@implementation GameScene
{


}

-(instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]){
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -2);
        SKNode *myWorld = [SKNode node];
        myWorld.zPosition = -1;
        [self addChild:myWorld];

        SKNode *camera = [SKNode node];

        [myWorld addChild:camera];

                  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
            SKSpriteNode * bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background.png"];
            bg.position = CGPointMake(i * bg.size.width, 0);
            bg.name = @"background.png";
            bg.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(-bg.frame.size.width/2, -bg.frame.size.height/2 +20) toPoint:CGPointMake(bg.frame.size.width/2, -bg.frame.size.height/2 + 20)];
            bg.physicsBody.restitution = 0.9;
            bg.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
            [myWorld addChild:bg];
        }

        SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball.png"];
        ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.height/2];
        ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = NO;
        ball.physicsBody.angularDamping = NO;
        ball.physicsBody.friction = 0;
        ball.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        ball.position = CGPointZero;
        ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.9;
        ball.zPosition = 1;
        ball.name = @"camera";
        ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(80, -30);
        SKAction *blockSpeed = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            CGVector speed = ball.physicsBody.velocity;
            speed.dx += 5;
            speed.dy -= 3;
            ball.physicsBody.velocity = speed;
        }];
        SKAction *waitAction2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:5.0];
        SKAction *sequenceAction2 = [SKAction sequence:@[blockSpeed, waitAction2]];
        SKAction *repeatAction2 = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequenceAction2];
        [ball runAction:repeatAction2];
        [myWorld addChild:ball];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKSpriteNode *block = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blockOne.png"];
    //block.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    block.position = CGPointMake(location.x, -100);
    block.physicsBody = [ SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:block.size];
    block.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    block.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    block.physicsBody.linearDamping = NO;
    block.physicsBody.angularDamping = NO;
    block.physicsBody.friction = 0;
    block.zPosition = 1;
    block.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    block.physicsBody.restitution = 0.9;
    block.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    SKAction *downBlock = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-10 duration:1.5];
    SKAction *removeBlock = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *blockSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[downBlock, removeBlock]];
    [self runAction:blockSequence];
    [self addChild:block];
    }
}

- (void)didFinishUpdate
{
    [self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName: @"//camera"]];
}

- (void) centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node
{
    CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x,                                       node.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y);
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"background" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x - 5, bg.position.y);
        if (bg.position.x <= -bg.size.width) {
            bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 2, bg.position.y);
        }
    }];

    }

@end
```

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this code, you do call [self addChild:block] so it should be in the node graph. You do not set an initial position for the block, so it'll be at 0x0 that's all I can tell. Please explain what the issue is here, what you see is happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I want the block to be added to the myWorld mode so that it collided with the physicsbody of the background node. Also I want the block to move out of the view along with the background when the ball goes further to the left. but now the block floats in the point of the touch in the view and moves with the view.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D please look into the question when free. I'm stuck on this got the scoring system and all other integrations ready. Thank you.